# compiling a c++ program using proj.4

Tags: proj

I am real new to C++ and am having trouble compiling a C++ program that uses the `proj.4` library. I downloaded and compiled and installed the `proj.4` library on my machine. So, the `/usr/local/lib`'contains

```
libproj.a  
libproj.la 
libproj.so -> libproj.so.0.6.6  
libproj.so.0 -> libproj.so.0.6.6  
libproj.so.0.6.6
```

and the `/usr/local/include` contains

```
nad_list.h  
org_proj4_Projections.h  
proj_api.h  
projects.h
```

and to compile my program `test.c`, I am using the following command

```
g++ -Wall -g first.c -lproj -o test
```

The compilation goes fine. But when I try to execute the program with `./test` I get the error message

```
./test: error while loading shared libraries: libproj.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I can't tell what I am missing here. Any help or suggestions here would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Linux Are you sure your LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set correctly? Alternatively you can edit your /etc/ld.so.conf file

If you are on Mac, [use the equivalent](http://macosx.com/forums/unix-x11/240354-problems-dyld-ld_library_path.html).